# I need in the RTF Layout as follow

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, curry-currency-converter

Convert the amount of the payment in currency: using either USD / AUD currency.
Example: "five hundred Dollars and twenty five Cents *"

I came across the following tags to BI Publisher available, but it was little different from my requirement.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you
Md.Alauddin

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details in order to be clear for someone trying to help you. Reading the guidelines will be helpful.